# Rails where select by arrays intersection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I had a table of Music. Each music has array of genres (genre is string).

Did i'm able to get list of music using where, than intersects at least at one genre?

As example, i had:

```
Music0.genres = ['1', '2', '3']

Music1.genres = ['4', '5', '6']

Music2.genres = ['2', '4', '6']
```

For Music0 result is Music2, and for Music2 - it's Music0 and Music1.

Comment: Please clearify: Are the genres stored in table on its own or as a string in a column on the music table?

Comment: Or an array column in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Or maybe they are already pre-loaded by the time you need to do your find?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `genres` is an array of strings on a model called `Music`, here's how you do it

```rb
genres_to_match = ['4', '6']

songs = Music.where("genres::text[] &&  && ARRAY[?]", genres_to_match)
# => Music1, Music2 should be the result
```